# Rails Application Admin Section

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am working on my first Rails application and want to create an admin section.

Do I want to keep my views and controllers completely separate (that is, in separate directories) for the admin section and the rest of the site?

How can I organize my views/controllers in custom directories (how do I configure the routing)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could also keep the apps and controllers in their usual places and use *Rails filters* to control access, which is what I think you're looking for here.

If you have the AWDWR Book handy, flip to Chap11 Task F Administrivia

- Basically define an authorize method in app\controllers\application.rb, which checks authorization, redirects to login page if not logged in et.all
- Mark controllers you want to restrict access to with `before_filter` s

.

```
class AdminController < ApplicationController
   before_filter :authorize
   #  ... the rest of the code
end
```

This will intercept all calls to actions defined in AdminController and force them to go via authorize

Comment: Might this complicate routing? I also like the idea of having separate directories just to keep things more orderly.

Comment: Not at all.. The beauty is that you don't have to define (or even mess with) different routes. Everything goes via a single path, the authorize before_filter ensures that only authorized requests get through to the protected actions.It's a 'declarative' approach..

Comment: That approach is ok, but not always appropriate, especially if you want to have an almost CMS like admin section as opposed to a few admin resources littered through your application.

Answer (score 8):

To create your admin controllers:

```
script/generate controller admin/articles
```

Then in your routes.rb file

```
map.resource :admin do |admin|
  admin.resources :articles, :path_prefix => "admin", :name_prefix => "admin_", :controller => "admin/articles"
end
```

You could then access the index url for this:

```
<%= link_to "Articles Admin", admin_articles_path %>
```

Answer (score 5):

```
map.namespace :admin do |admin|
  admin.register :controller => 'main', :action => 'register'
  admin.login, :controller => 'main', action => 'login'
  # ...
end
```

This is how you namespace things, add this to the other comments here about authorizing things and you're away. Have a look at the restful_authentication plugin to do your user management, much quicker and easier than rolling your own.

The above routing assumes the controllers and their views are in a subdirectory called admin, which I think is what you want.